# Linq orderBy по стороннему параметру

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Как сортировать объекты по моему параметру?

Например, вместо этого

```
var show=(from n in db.Players
orderBy n.Country
select n);
```

сделать так

```
var show=(from n in db.Players
orderBy columnName
select n);
```

Comment: Эээ... Вы можете сортировать лишь элементы таблицы между собой. Ваше `columnName` есть поле в элементе таблицы или вычисляется по нему? Или это какая-то сторонняя штука?

Расскажите вашу настоящую задачу.

Comment: Через синтаксис запросов в любом случае не получится. Через синтаксис методов так можно сделать, примеров много, например http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите сортировать по произвольной колонке, заданной строковой переменной, вам лучше посмотреть на [Dynamic Linq](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/documentation). Или же преобразовывать Expression Tree с помощью ExpressionVisitor